# Windows 8 Store Application Connecting to SQL Online Databse

Tags: c#, mysql, database, windows, microsoft-metro

Ok I have searched and searched for an answer to my problem but can not find a direct answer.

**Can someone please guide me in the direction I need to go with step by step solution somewhere that is useful?**

My Question:

I built an `Windows 8.1 Metro Application` that needs to pull data and store data into a database I am hosting in `MySQL` online but I can not use things like `My.SQL.Data.RT` because it is not supported (I guess) because I get an error.

**How do I connect to my online database to pull information from and store information to it? If I can not do this what options do I have?**

Using local databases is not an option because everyone will be storing information in the database and pulling information from it from hundreds of different computers running the application.

If you could point me to a website that I can see it in step by step and please. I am using `C#`.

Thank you for your help. I have been racking my brain over this because the `My.SQL.Data.RT` works but the application fails to pass the `Windows Store` requirements with it pretty dumb if you ask me.

Comment: Use a service to fetch the data,it will pass the windows certification.[Consuming Windows 8 with wcf](http://tapanila.net/consuming-wcf-service-with-windows-8/) also see [msdn doucmentation about winRT -wcf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows 8 store app developer so I am just trying to give suggestions.

From what I know, **connecting directly to database server over internet from a client app is NOT A GOOD PRACTICE nowadays**. Instead, people provide APIs to do it.

For example, Twitter provides **restful APIs**, so twitter clients can request http urls and get wanted data in JOSN format. The security of the the connection is ensured by oAuth (so that you don't transfer username and password in http request) and SSL/HTTPS.

In this way, the database connection is hidden from Internet. You will also benefit from the API layer if you want to develop another client on platforms other than Windows, e.g. iOS or Android.

By a quick google search, I found two guides about making a restful api with C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112470/Developing-a-REST-Web-Service-using-C-A-walkthroug
http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api